# Django admin: list not correct (duplicate rows)

Tags: django, django-admin

My `admin.py` is like this:

```
class ResizableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
        }
        js = ('js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js',)

class GroupeMotsForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
    mots = django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Mot.objects.all().order_by('groupes__description', 'texte'),
        widget=django.forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'resize_dst'})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = GroupeMots
        fields = ['description', 'admin_taille_fenetre', 'mots', ]
        widgets = {
            'admin_taille_fenetre': django.forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={'class': 'resize_src'}
            )
        }


class GroupeMotsAdmin(ResizableAdmin):
    form = GroupeMotsForm
```

In my database I have only one row in GroupeMots:

[image: only one row in GroupeMots]

It's displayed 3 times in the list of the admin interface:

[image: displayed 3 times in the list]

Any idea where to look? Where could Django look to have 3 results? They all point to the same record. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My model is like that:

```
class GroupeMots(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    mots = models.ManyToManyField(Mot, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['mots__texte']

    def __str__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(
            self.description
        )
```

And the problem came from `ordering = ['mots__texte']` because there seems to be 3 results, so "ordering" generates dupes... I changed it to `description` and now it's ok